# cKeditor and Elfinder don't load files to assets

Tags: yii2

After putting site to hosting, ckEditor and ElFinder don't work. I Tried to see view-source in browser

```
  <script src="/assets/15f6a66f/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

This and other files in assets folder doesn't exists. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using this url hardcoded somewhere ? where is it coming from.

Comment: This script link from site which i put in hosting (from page which i use ckEditor). I compared page with local site. In local site when i delete folder assets It generate files in folder assets , but when i put it in hosting it doesn't generate files in assets. It generated script link , but files (ckeditor.js and etc.) doesn't exists in folder assets

Comment: you need to install the extension using `composer require` should not copy the extension, if that is the case.

Comment: Is there another way to do this, because i have only ftp access to server i can't use composer

Comment: which composer package are you using for `CKEditor` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proplem is solved! I made some changes in WebConfig:

```
'components' => [
    'assetManager' => [
        'linkAssets' => true,
    ],
],
```

Another  issue was on permission .htaccess. I changed owner permission to Read, Write and Execute with FileZilla. Both work